# xstl apply-template (call tempalate) with variable and use in xsl:evaluate

Tags: variables, xslt, xls, xslt-3.0

I have the following xml:

```
<pi:Payroll_Extract_Employees xmlns:pi="urn:com.workday/picof">
   <pi:company>
      <pi:Employee>
         <pi:name>John Andrews</pi:name>
         <pi:age>23</pi:age>
         <pi:salary>4000</pi:salary>
         <pi:division>Accounting</pi:division>
      </pi:Employee>
   </pi:company>
</pi:Payroll_Extract_Employees>
```

I am using this transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:pi="urn:com.workday/picof">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:template match="pi:Payroll_Extract_Employees/pi:company">
        <xsl:variable name="tabsNames">
            <entry>
                <spreadSheetName>Payroll Data for Taiwan</spreadSheetName>
                <values>
                    <value>
                        <header>Chinese Name</header>
                        <data>/pi:Name</data>
                    </value>
                </values>
            </entry>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="currentNode" select="."/>
        <xsl:for-each select="$tabsNames/entry">
            <xsl:variable name="dataValues" select="values/value/data"/>

            <xsl:call-template name="employeeRows">
                <xsl:with-param name="rows" select="$dataValues" as="element()*"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="currentNode" select="$currentNode" as="element()"/>
            </xsl:call-template>

        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="employeeRows">
        <xsl:param name="rows" select="."/>
        <xsl:param name="currentNode" select="."/>

        <xsl:for-each select="$currentNode/pi:Employee">
            <xsl:variable name="employee" select="." as="element()"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="$rows">
                <xsl:variable name="path" select="."/>
                <xsl:value-of>
                    <xsl:evaluate xpath="$employee || $path" context-item="."/>
                    <!--<xsl:value-of select="$employee/pi:name"/>-->
                </xsl:value-of>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here I am creating a map $tabNames and the would like to pass map together with current node to employeeRows template. Instead of data values for "rows" parameter I get entire map and instead of current node (pi:Payroll_Extract_Employees/pi:company) for currentNode parameter I receive the same map as for the "rows" parameter.
The second problem is that xsl:evaluates changes $employee to a value I would like following to give me the same output

```
<xsl:evaluate xpath="$employee || $path" context-item="."/>
```

as this

```
<xsl:value-of select="$employee/pi:Name"/>
```

What I have so far throws an error here:

```
<xsl:evaluate xpath="$employee || $path" context-item="."/>
```

Error message:

System ID: C:\Users\przemekb\AppData\Local\Temp\Untitled4.xsl
Severity: fatal
Description: Static error in XPath expression supplied to xsl:evaluate: Unexpected token name "Andrews" beyond end of expression. Expression: { John Andrews 23 4000 Accounting pi:Name}
Start location: 36:42
Length: 1

Comment: Please spell out what "I have been trying to use apply-templates" and "it doesn't work" means exactly by showing minimal but complete samples of XML, XSLT, result you get, result you want, to allow us to understand and reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have updated the question, hopefully its more readable now

Comment: Why do you have `xpath-default-namespace="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"` in that snippet although that namespace is not used anywhere in your input or stylesheet as posted. Using `for-each select="$tabsNames/entry"` does not select anything I would say, given the details shown.

Comment: I remove the namespace but I am still getting  an error:
<xsl:evaluate xpath="$employee || $path" context-item="."/>
what I need is not to evaluate $employee , do you think it is possible?

Comment: It sounds more as if you want that employee to be the context item and want your path to be `<data>pi:Name</data>` in that case.

Comment: can't believe it was that simple, thx

Comment: But anyway is it possible to use a variable in xsl:evaluate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps your

```
<xsl:evaluate xpath="$employee || $path" context-item="."/>
```

should be either

```
<xsl:evaluate xpath="'$employee' || $path">
  <xsl:with-param name="employee" select="$employee"/>
</xsl:evaluate>
```

or simply

```
<xsl:evaluate xpath="$path" context-item="$employee"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I suspect that in this element

   `<data>pi:Summary/pi:Name</data>`

the content is intended to be an XPath expression, and that you expect this XPath expression to be evaluated. That's not a correct expectation; use an xsl:value-of instruction.

2. I suspect that

   `<xsl:variable name="dataValues" select="values/value/data"/>`

should be

```
<xsl:variable name="dataValues" select="$tabsName/entry/values/value/data"/>
```

though I can't account for the output you said you got.

3. In this:

`<xsl:with-param name="currentNode" select="." as="node()*"/>`

there's something amiss because "." will always be a singleton, so why does the "as" attribute suggest it might be a sequence?

Comment: thank you for your answer, I am not expecting it to be evaluated I just would like to have it stored in a map as text, and would like to have it used in xsl:evaluate, maybe my questoion is a little miss leading let me correct that.